# How can I import @react-native-firebase FilterFunction?

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to use a FilterFunction(https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/filterfunction).
And I copied a example as bellow

```
const snapshot = await firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .where(
    Filter.or(
      Filter.and(Filter('user', '==', 'Tim'), Filter('email', '==', 'tim@example.com')),
      Filter.and(Filter('user', '==', 'Dave'), Filter('email', '==', 'dave@example.com')),
    ),
  )
  .get();
```

(I referred it from https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#filtering)

But I cannot get a `Filter` from anywhere.

It occurs this error message. `Cannot find name 'Filter'.`

How Can I use FilterFunction?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue and use the `Filter` function correctly, you need to ensure that you import it correctly from the `rnfirebase` library.

To use the `Filter` function from the `FilterFunction` module, you can modify your code as follows:

```
import { FilterFunction } from 'rnfirebase/firestore';
// Make sure to import the 'FilterFunction' from the correct module

const snapshot = await firestore()
  .collection('Users')
  .where(
    FilterFunction.or(
      FilterFunction.and(FilterFunction('user', '==', 'Tim'), FilterFunction('email', '==', 'tim@example.com')),
      FilterFunction.and(FilterFunction('user', '==', 'Dave'), FilterFunction('email', '==', 'dave@example.com')),
    ),
  )
  .get();
```

Comment: I'm using `@react-native-firebase/firestore` not `rnfirebase/firestore`. Did you mean `@react-native-firebase/firestore`?
And I think they didn't exported a FilterFunction in this version.
It seems they handling it now. check this link. `https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7134`